# Extract features from satellite images and store the features as a shapefile?

Tags: geocoding, feature-extraction

I am trying to identify boundaries, blocks etc from Satellite images which are stored as GeoTIFF files. I want to extract fields, buildings etc. by feature recognition and store that as GeoJSON/shapefile files.

Are there any opensource tools/libraries which I can implement to do that?

Comment: Please see the StackOverflow rules for ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Software recommendations are simply too broad for the focused Q&A format--and there's not a "right" answer.  *(Especially when you haven't even specified a language!)*  Try browsing through Wikipedia's list of [Open Source GIS software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geographic_information_systems_software#Open_source_software) and see what might fit your needs, and if you encounter a specific question trying to use one of them (programming related) then that's on topic.

Comment: Is your question about automatic feature recognition, or is it simply about what tools to use to aid manual feature creation using a basemap for assistance?